# How is return address specified in stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, calling-convention

This is what I see by disassemble for the statement `function(1,2,3);`:

```
movl   $0x3,0x8(%esp)
movl   $0x2,0x4(%esp)
movl   $0x1,(%esp)
call   0x4012d0 <_Z8functioniii>
```

It seems the *ret address* is not pushed into stack at all,then how does `ret` work?

Answer (score 11):

On an x86 processor (as for your assembly language example), the [`call`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call) instruction pushes the return address on the stack and transfers control to the function.

So on entry to a function, the stack pointer is pointing at a return address, ready for `ret` to pop it into the program counter (EIP / RIP).

---

Not all processor architectures put the return address on the stack- often there's a set of one or more registers designed to hold return addresses. On ARM processors, the `BL` instruction places the return address in a specific register (`LR`, or the 'link register') and transfers control to the function.

The ia64 processor does something similar, except that there are several possible registers (`b0`-`b7`) that can receive the return address and one will be specified in the instruction (with `b0` being the default).

Answer (score 6):

Ideally, the `call` statement should take care of that. The program counter's next location will be pushed into the stack. When the function (sub routine) that was called completes it work and when it encounters a return statement, the control now goes to the address that was pushed into the stack and it will get popped.

Comment: How does `call` deal with it then?I just want to see where the *ret address* is specified

Comment: You will have break down the call method to further hex code. The cheat sheet for instruction set specified for the particular processor would reveal that. For example if you take the simplest of microprocessors 8085 and ADD X instruction will not show the second value (lets assume Y like ADD X,Y). Instead it will add the value X to some reserved register within the processor say H and store the value in H. The overflow bit should there be any will be stored in another register. That is how ADD instruction is designed. CALL instruction also will have similar predefined rules

Comment: Part of the job of the call instruction is to push the return address onto the stack. The return address is just the address directly after the parameters to the call instruction. To see what the return address is in your example above, you'd have to look at the stack as soon as the program gets into the procedure at 0x4012d0.

Comment: @Mask, you can think that return address is passed as address of call instruction stored in IP/EIP register. when processor gets next insruction and it's call instruction (far/short etc.) it can add size of instruction to IP and push it to stack (SP register) with doing this it will change value of IP to appropriate address ref passed with CALL instruction (relative for short, absolute for far, register based etc.). P.S. Is this question is still have no approved answers?..

Comment: @ony this is the answer I've been looking for.. When I set a bp on a CALL instruction, I see the current address in RIP + 1  pushed to the stack. Every document I have read states that it's RIP that gets pushed, but that's not what I see when debugging.

Comment: @Kayla0x41, it is simple a matter of miss of sync on when "current" is refers to. Apparently in documents it was referring to moment after instruction was read and IP/EIP/RIP increased (different call instructions have different length and not necessary word size). I also used to think "current address" is the one for next instruction to execute.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the ABI and the architecture, but if the return address does end up on the stack it's a side-effect of the `call` instruction that puts it there.

Answer (score 1):

**call** pushes the current value of the RIP register (return address) to the stack + does the call
**ret** pops the return address(that **call** pushed) from the top of the stack (RSP register points there) and writes it in the RIP register.

Example on a GNU/Linux box: function f calls function g and lets look at the frame of g.

**LOW ADDRESS**

...                     <- RSP (stack pointer shows top of stack) register points at this address
g's local vars
f's base pointer (old RBP value)    <- RBP (base pointer) register points at this address
f's ret address  (old RIP value) (this is what the **call** (from f) pushed, and what the **ret** (from g) will pop)
args that f called g with and didn't fit in the registers    (I think on Windows this is different)
...

**HIGH ADDRESS**

g will free the local vars (movq    %rsp, %rbp)
g will pop the "old RBP" and store it in RBP register (pop %rbp)
g will **ret**, which will modify RIP with the value that is stored where RSP points at

Hope it helps